# How can I use boolean variable in this method to exit out of while for-loop?

Tags: java, loops, boolean, queue, exit

I have a method that finds the position of a specific element in a queue and returns the position. I am finding the position by using the n counter and incrementing every time until I find the element and returning n which would be the position. However, when i try to execute the loop, it is endless and doesn't exit on its own. I am confused on which part of my loop should I add the boolean.

I have declared the boolean variable here:

```
public class LinkedQueue<T> implements QueueADT<T> {
    boolean found=false;
    private int n;
    private LinearNode<T> first, last;
    private LinearNode<T> T;
```

This is my method:

```
public int position(T element) throws EmptyQueueException, NoSuchElementException {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmptyQueueException("Queue is empty");
        }
        LinearNode<T> node = first;

        n = 0;
        while (node != null) {
            if (node.getElement().equals(element)) {
                found = true;
                System.out.println(n);
            }
            n++;
            node.getNext();
        }
        return n;
```

The loop is endless and this is a snippet of how far the counter goes before I have to cancel the run.

```
142215
142216
142217
142218
142219
142220
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Comment: You never update `node`. You need `node = node.getNext()`

Answer (score 0):

You can always use below approach

```
while (node != null) {
            if (node.getElement().equals(element)) {
                System.out.println(n);
                break;
            }
            n++;
            node.getNext();
        }
```

Comment: i added break and even though it doesn't result in an endless loop, the main method keeps running without any output

Comment: Can you share your code on a git repo , so i can help by checking it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what condition you want to exit. In this code you are saying untill the node is null, keep iterating and printing. So if node is not equal to null, it will keep iterating, Instead i would suggest you to take a boolean outside while loop. Once you get the data you need, make the boolean true/false whatever is your goal.
Example:
boolean found = false;

```
while(!found){
//Your code for dessired result, when result is received,
found = true;
}
```